# Php Prepared Statement Fails to insert data into database through form

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, multipartform-data, insert-update

I'm trying to insert data into a database, the script executes all the way down and redirect the user to the page but no record gets inserted. I've been trying to figure out why for hours. I keep creating new scripts but i'm missing something apparently.

**init.php**

```
<?php
/*for error 1045 config.inc.php*/
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "databasename");
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "database failed to connect with following errors:". mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ecommerce/config.php';
require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';
```

**form.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/HeleneQuirion/core/init.php';
include 'includes/header.php'; 

if(isset($_GET['add'])){
$parentQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent= 0" );

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO product (prod_name, categories, list_price, price,prod_width,prod_depth,prod_height,prod_material,quantity,image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4,description,care_instructions) VALUES (?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssiiiiisissssss" ,$prod_name, $child,$list_price,$price,$prod_width,$prod_depth,$prod_height,$prod_material,$quantity,$image_1,$image_2,$image_3,$image_4,$description,$care_instructions);

// set parameters and execute
 if(isset($_POST['prod_name']))
    {
        $prod_name = sanitize($_POST)['prod_name'];    
    }

         if(isset($_POST['child']))
    {
        $categories = sanitize($_POST)['child'];    
    }

         if(isset($_POST['list_price']))
    {
        $prod_name = sanitize($_POST)['list_price'];    
    }

          if(isset($_POST['price']))
    {
        $price =  sanitize($_POST)['price'];    
    }

         if(isset($_POST['prod_width']))
    {
        $prod_width = sanitize($_POST)['prod_width'];    
    }

       if(isset($_POST['prod_depth']))
    {
        $prod_depth =  sanitize($_POST)['prod_depth'];    
    }

           if(isset($_POST['prod_height']))
    {
        $prod_height =  sanitize($_POST)['prod_height'];    
    }

           if(isset($_POST['prod_material']))
    {
        $prod_material =  sanitize($_POST)['prod_material'];    
    }

           if(isset($_POST['quantity']))
    {
        $quantity = sanitize($_POST)['quantity'];    
    }

       if(isset($_POST['care_instructions']))
    {
        $care_instructions = sanitize($_POST)['care_instructions'];    
    }

    if(isset($_POST['image_1']))
    {
        $image_1 =  $_FILES['image_1'];    
    }

       if(isset($_POST['image_2']))
    {
        $image_2 = $_FILES['image_2'];    
    }

       if(isset($_POST['image_3']))
    {
        $image_3 = $_FILES['image_3'];    
    }

       if(isset($_POST['image_4']))
    {
        $image_4 =  $_FILES['image_4'];    
    }

       if(isset($_POST['description']))
    {
        $description =  sanitize($_POST)['description'];
    }
$stmt->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
header('Location: products.php');

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
 } 
?>


     <form action="products.php?add=1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class='container_12'>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="prod_name">Product Name*:</label>
                     <input type="text" name="prod_name" id="prod_name" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['prod_name']))?sanitize($_POST['prod_name']):' ');?>">


                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="parent">Parent Category*:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="parent" name="parent"> 
                        <option value=""<?=((isset($_POST['parent']) && $_POST['parent'] == '')?'selected':'');?>></option> 
                            <?php while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentQuery)): ?> 
                        <option value=" <?=$parent['id'];?>"<?=((isset($_POST['parent']) && $_POST['parent'] == $parent['id'])?' select':'');?>><?=$parent['category_name'];?></option> 
                            <?php endwhile; ?> 
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group col-md-3'>
                    <label for='child'>Second Category*:</label>
                    <select id='child' name='child' class='form-control'></select>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class='container_12'>

                    <div class='form-group col-md-3'>
                            <label for='list_price'>List Price(OPTIONAL): </label>
                            <input type="text" id="list_price" name="list_price" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['list_price']))?sanitize($_POST['list_price']):'');?>">
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="price">Price*:</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['price']))?sanitize($_POST['price']):'');?>"> 
                </div>

                 <div class='form-group col-md-3'>
                            <label for='prod_width'>Width* (in inches):</label>
                            <input type="text" id="prod_width" name="prod_width" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['prod_width']))?sanitize($_POST['prod_width']):'');?>">
                    </div>

                 <div class='form-group col-md-3'>
                            <label for='prod_depth'>Height*(in inches):</label>
                            <input type="text" id="'prod_depth" name="'prod_depth" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['prod_depth']))?sanitize($_POST['prod_depth']):'');?>">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='container_12'>
                 <div class='form-group col-md-3'>
                            <label for='prod_height'>Depth*(in inches):</label>
                            <input type="text" id="prod_height" name="prod_height" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['prod_height']))?sanitize($_POST['prod_height']):'');?>">
                    </div>

                <div class='form-group col-md-3'>
                            <label for='prod_material'>Construction Material:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="prod_material" name="prod_material" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['prod_material']))?sanitize($_POST['prod_material']):'');?>">

                </div>

                <div class='form-group col-md-6'>
                    <label>Quantity * :</label>
                      <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['quantity']))?sanitize($_POST['quantity']):'');?>">

                </div>
                </div>

                <div class='container_12'>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3"> <label for="image_1">Product Photo #1:</label> 
                    <input type="file" name="image_1" id="image_1" class="form-control"> 
                </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3"> <label for="image_2">Product Photo #2:</label> 
                    <input type="file" name="image_2" id="image_2" class="form-control"> 
                </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3"> <label for="image_3">Product Photo #3:</label> 
                    <input type="file" name="image_3" id="image_3" class="form-control"> 
                </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3"> <label for="image_4">Product Photo#4:</label> 
                    <input type="file" name="image_4" id="image_4" class="form-control"> 
                </div>

                </div>



                <div class='container_12'>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="description">Description:</label>
                    <textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control" rows="6"><?=((isset($_POST['description']))?sanitize($_POST['description']):'');?></textarea> 
                </div>



                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="care_instructions">Care Instructions*:</label>
                    <textarea id="care_instructions" name="care_instructions" class="form-control" rows="6"><?=((isset($_POST['care_instructions']))?sanitize($_POST['care_instructions']):'');?></textarea> 
                  </div></div>

                <div class='container_12'>
                    <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Product' class='form-control btn-success pull-right'>
                    </div></div>
                                   </form>
```

Comment: `?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?` != `sss`. Define your data types. Also use error reporting.

Comment: Why call `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ecommerce/core/init.php';` and then hard code another `$conn= mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);` after calling `init`

Comment: Errrmmm you also load `helpers` twice and I am only down to line 5 of `form.php`

Comment: @chris85: I'm relativity new to Php... You mean to  replace `?` by actual values like for example `$value`? And `sss` should be defining each single data? Meaning to have it match the number of times they are values?

Comment: No he probably means [Read the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: No how am I calling it twice? I'm calling `init.php` in which i'm calling `helpers.php`

Comment: No, don't do that. Each `s` is representing a `string` you are binding. A letter per variable. You have 15 (i think) placeholders, so you should have 15 datatypes defined. The `i` is for integer so the manual for other types,

Comment: if you have 2 question marks you need to bing 2 parameters. So 12 `?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?` means you need 12 type definitions (s or d or i or b) and 12 values **RTM**

Comment: @RiggsFolly: line 7 of form.php is `include 'includes/header.php';` and line 14 of init.php is `require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';` call me dumb but they are 2 different files.

Comment: Yea ok, my mistake on that one, its late, gone midnight

Comment: @chris85: yes that is what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: Well actually you are including init.php to establish a mysqli_connect and then you hardcode in another mysqli_connect in form.php. Why do you need to do that twice?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw: For dev purposes only. Relax.

Comment: I am :) Did you notice your rogue $email in your bind_params thats not in your prepare statement...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw: Yes I just did. Everything seems ok now except for this nasty error `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\helpers\helpers.php on line 11` the sanitize function is the problem.

Comment: You just need to change up your call to sanitize... like...$prod_name = sanitize($_POST['prod_name']);

Comment: I'd even go as far as $prod_name = isset($_POST['prod_name'])? sanitize($_POST['prod_name']):''; like you have done in your form itself. To be consistent.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw: That's exactly how the code already is no?

Comment: Which means you are sanitizing it twice. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @WorldOutside, No... my eyeballs see - $prod_name = sanitize($_POST)['prod_name'];  which results in passing prod_name as an array. A structure I've not come across before but I tried it and it works... So that's a new one on me!

Comment: Just put some testing code in my answer below to highlight what I mean...

Comment: You are welcome. You can learn a lot by just ripping out some code in isolation and have a play with it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to clarify one of the points in the comments above...
So I knocked up some test code to check what is going on...

```
<?php

$_POST['prod_name'] = 'fred';

function sanitize($thing){
    var_dump("Inside Sanitize- ", $thing);
    return $thing;
}
// Original Code - sends an array to sanitize
if(isset( $_POST['prod_name'] )) {
    $prod_name = sanitize($_POST)['prod_name'];
}
var_dump('Original Version '.$prod_name);

// New Code 1 - Sends a String to sanitize
if(isset( $_POST['prod_name'] )) {
    $prod_name = sanitize($_POST['prod_name']);
}

// New Code 2 - Should use this one, or could make this a function.
$prod_name = isset($_POST['prod_name'])? sanitize($_POST['prod_name']):'';

var_dump($prod_name);
```